# OpenCV - best approach to detect different objects real-time

Tags: opencv, image-processing

My objective is to find at least two different objects at real-time with OpenCV. I have tried using SURF, but it is working for one object at a time.

```
-> I don't want to detect multiple occurrence of an object.
-> The technique should detect different objects at a time.
```

Please suggest me any approach to handle this problem.

Comment: Could you show us a little more of what you already tried? I would suggest using `findcontours`...

Comment: @elactic, Thank you for the interest. I have tried some examples on SURF technique and one of them I had posted earlier, you can check that  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853020/multiple-object-detection-with-open-cv) here. I need some suggestions on how do I detect different objects at a time. Please help me on this.

Comment: For a more better clarity, please look at [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14678/best-approach-to-detect-different-objects-real/). I have posted the required output image there. Please help me on this problem.

Comment: If SURF works for one object, why don't you run it twice inside the frame for two objects?

Comment: @Vikas Probaby not a great idea to put an image with your credit card details on the net!

Answer (score 0):

Any approach?

1. Make sure the objects are on the gray background and not overlapping.
2. Ignore the gray background.
3. Any big black blob is a phone.
4. Any mostly gold and brown blob is your ATM card